# Modals in Materialize Framework

Tags: javascript, materialize

I made a modal with materialize framework. I want the modal to open just in the corner of the button. getBoundingClientRect doesn't work. How can I do it?
Here is my code:

```
<li id="li2">
        <label id="labelSimple" style="padding-left: 37px;">
            <input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox">
            <span id="checkHeader" style="left:18px !important">Click</span>
        </label>
        <i id="i" class="material-icons modal-trigger" style="float:right; position:relative;text-align:-webkit-match-parent; top:9px; color:#9e9e9e;cursor:pointer" href="#collapse010">more_vert</i>

</li>
   <div class="modal" id="collapse010" tabindex="0">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="collection">
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item">a</a>
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item ">b</a>
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item">c</a>
            <li>
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </li>
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls add code to your question